# My infinite scroll plugin keeps appending the same content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So the jquery plugin I'm using keeps on contentiously appending the same content which is the content within the ul id "next". How do I prevent it from appending within the infinite scroll more than once?

Here's the endless scroll plugin

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
       $(document.body).append($("ul#next").html());
   }
});
```

Comment: what do you want to do when the scollbar reaches the bottom?

Comment: I want it to append content from a list of images in my html, for example this list in my html <ul id="next"> <li>image link</li> </ul>, but when the infinite scroll appends them when I reach the bottom, it keeps on appending them when I scroll again and again, I only want it to append once. This means if I scroll after it appends once, it shouldn't append anything afterwards.

Comment: In that case you need to maintain the variable that would hold the value of lastly added image's index from the list and you can add next if needed.

Comment: Try replacing `$(document.body).append($("ul#next").html());` with `$(document.body).stop().append($("ul#next").html());`

Comment: No use adding `.stop()` since nothing is being animated.

Comment: @vinayakj So how would this look exactly?  Lets say I've got this content on the top of the page: <ul id="images"> <li>image link</li> </ul> and I want to append this: <ul id="next"> <li>image link</li> </ul>. What would the code look like for this example?

Comment: If its just a one time and one image ul list then have some kinda flag var.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var alreadyAdded = false;
   $(window).scroll(function () { 
     if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10 && !alreadyAdded) {
       $(document.body).append($("ul#next").html());
       alreadyAdded = true;
     }
   })
```